# Django's Success messages displayed like error messages

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I'm working on a Django project and I'm using Django's built-in messaging framework to display success and error messages to the user. However, I'm encountering an issue where success messages are being displayed in a way that makes them look like error messages.error messages displyed like success messages

here is my Html code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}
<div class="mx-auto max-w-screen-xl px-4 py-16 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-lg">
      {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            {% if message.tags == 'success' %}
                <div class="rounded border-s-4 mb-1 border-green-500 bg-emerald-50 p-4">
                  <strong class="block font-medium text-green-800"> Successfully </strong>
                
                  <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-green-700">
                      {{ message }}
                  </p>
              </div>
            {% else%}
                <div class="rounded border-s-4 mb-1 border-red-500 bg-red-50 p-4">
                  <strong class="block font-medium text-red-800"> Something went wrong </strong>
                  <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-red-700">
                      {{ message }}
                  </p>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}

      <h1 class="text-center text-2xl font-bold text-black sm:text-3xl">Book Appointment</h1>
  
      <p class="mx-auto mt-4 max-w-md text-center text-gray-500">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati sunt
        dolores deleniti inventore quaerat mollitia?
      </p>
  
      <form method="post" action="" class="mb-0 mt-6 space-y-4 rounded-lg p-4 shadow-lg sm:p-6 lg:p-8">
        <p class="text-center text-lg font-medium">Appointment form</p>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <label for="name" class="sr-only">Name</label>
  
          <div class="relative">
            <input type="text" type="text" name="name" class="w-full rounded-lg border-gray-200 p-4 pe-12 text-sm shadow-sm outline-blue-600" placeholder="Enter name">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
    
            <div class="relative">
              <input type="text" type="email" name="email" class="w-full rounded-lg border-gray-200 p-4 pe-12 text-sm shadow-sm outline-blue-600" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div>
            <label for="phonenumber" class="sr-only">Phone number</label>
    
            <div class="relative">
              <input type="tel" name="phone_number" class="w-full rounded-lg border-gray-200 p-4 pe-12 text-sm shadow-sm outline-blue-600" placeholder="Enter phone number" maxlength="10">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="block w-full rounded-lg bg-black px-5 py-3 text-sm font-medium text-white">Book appointment</button>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

here is my views.py code

```
def create_appointment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        phone_number = request.POST.get('phone_number')
        date_str = request.session.get('date')
        time = request.session.get('time')

        date = datetime.fromisoformat(date_str)

        if Appointment.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'This email is already booked for an appointment.', extra_tags='error')
            return redirect('appointment')

        if Appointment.objects.filter(phone_number=phone_number).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'This Phone number is already booked for an appointment.', extra_tags='error')
            return redirect('appointment')

        booking = Appointment.objects.create(name=name, email=email, phone_number=phone_number, date=date, time=time, user=request.user)
        booking.save()

        subject = 'Appointment Confirmation'
        message = f'Thank you for the appointment \n\n Dear {booking.name},\n\nYour appointment for {booking.date.date()} at {booking.time} has been successfully booked.\n\nYour token number is: {booking.token} \n\nPhone Number: {booking.phone_number}\n\nIf you want to cancel the appointment, just call: 91XXXXXXXX \n\nThank you!'
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER 
        recipient_list = [booking.email]

        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False)
        messages.success(request, 'Appointment created successfully.', extra_tags='success')
        del request.session['date']
        del request.session['time']
        return redirect('appointment')  

    return render(request, 'appointment.html' , {'time':'appointment' , 'title':'Appointment'})
```

click for image
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVq0z.png)

Comment: please upload your Django code as well, it would be helpful for debugging.

Comment: @nithinks
tnx for responding now updated my code

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to the way you are handling message tags in your template. In your code you are checking if the message tags are exactly equal to 'success' or not and if not you assume it is an error message. This approach may not work correctly because there might be other tags attached to the success messages. You can modify your code in a different way like: check if 'success' is in the message tags this will allow you to handle success messages better even if they have additional tags attached.
For example:

```
{% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            {% if 'success' in message.tags %}
                <div class="rounded border-s-4 mb-1 border-green-500 bg-emerald-50 p-4">
                  <strong class="block font-medium text-green-800"> Successfully </strong>
                
                  <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-green-700">
                      {{ message }}
                  </p>
              </div>
            {% else %}
                <div class="rounded border-s-4 mb-1 border-red-500 bg-red-50 p-4">
                  <strong class="block font-medium text-red-800"> Something went wrong </strong>
                  <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-red-700">
                      {{ message }}
                  </p>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
```